# Unique readability theorem proof using the set-theoretic definition of formulas

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, propositional-calculus, alternative-proof

Definition: Let $X$ be the set of all the symbols on the alphabet of propositional logic, and also let the set $Z$ be the set of all the subsets $Y$ of $X$ such that: if $\alpha$ $\in$ $Y$ then ($\lnot$ $\alpha$) $\in$  $Y$, and if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ belong to $Y$ then ($\alpha$ $\circ$ $\beta$) $\in$ $Y$, such that $\circ$ $\in$ $\{$$\land$, $\lor$, $\to$, $\leftrightarrow$$\}$

We can easily prove the Induction on the Complexity of Formulas as from the definition of formulas  above: Let $F$ be the intersection of the family of sets $Z$, then we have that $F$ satisfies the conditions listened above and the is the smallest set (let all the $Y_n$ be all of the elements of $Z$, then it follows that $F$ $\subseteq$ $Y_1$ $\subseteq$  $Y_2$ $\subseteq$ ... $\subseteq$ $Y_n$) such that it belongs to $Z$. As we have a well-founded relation $\subseteq$ on $Z$, then we end the proof by structural induction.

Now, making use of the theorem above, how does one prove the Unique Readibility Theorem? It objectively states that for every formula $A$, one, and only one of the following affirmations are true: (1):= $A$ is atomic, (2):= There is an unique formula $B$ such that $A$ is ($\lnot$$B$), (3):= There are unique formulas $B$ and $C$ such that $A$ is ($B$ $\land$ $C$), or, either, ($B$ $\lor$ C), ($B$ $\to$ $C$), or ($B$ $\leftrightarrow$ $C$).

Comment: Your definitions are slightly off. You should start by considering a fixed set $Q$ of atomic propositions. Then, you should let $X = Q \cup \{(, ), \neg, \lor, \land, \iff\}$. Then $Z$ should be the set of all $Y$ such that $Q \subseteq Y \subseteq X^*$ and $Y$ is closed under $\neg$ and the binary operations. Here, $X^*$ is the free monoid on $X$, aka the set of strings on $X$, and we abusively have $X \subseteq X^*$.

Comment: I think that saying "sets" when in fact it is "strings" is more than slightly off.

Comment: You can visualize $X$ as being the set of all finite strings on the alphabet.